# On click of non-verbal button present in the image I want to display menu with 4 rows and 4 column in the space below the code how can I do that?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[Image shows a screen that returns a SingleChildScrollView.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtHgI.jpg)

Structure looks like
SingleChildScrollView

```
  -Column
      -new Card
      -new Card
      -new Card
         -Row
      -new Card
         -new RaisedButton(Noise)
         -new RaisedButton(SkipJob)
         -new RaisedButton(Non-verbal) -----------> *(this-button)
```

*(this-button) On clicking this button I want a widget to appear having a certain height that fits in the frame with 4 rows and 4 columns like a calculator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
Column(
 children:[
          Row(children:[Text('1'),Text('2'),Text('3'),Text('4'),],),
          Row(children:[Text('5'),Text('6'),Text('7'),Text('8'),],),
          Row(children:[Text('9'),Text('10'),Text('11'),Text('12'),],),
          Row(children:[Text('13'),Text('14'),Text('15'),Text('16'),],),
          ],),
```

Can maybe wrap the `Column` in a `Expanded` widget to take the full space left.